# Configured Google Document AI to enable "computeStyleInfo", but not receiving any textStyles in the response

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, ocr, cloud-document-ai

The textStyles array from the Document AI response object is empty, despite having set everything up following google's docAI documentation.

I enabled document AI's font-style detection following google's documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/process-documents-ocr#font-style_detection).

In my server, the request is built as follows

```
const request: google.cloud.documentai.v1.IProcessRequest | undefined = {
      name,
      rawDocument: {
        content,
        mimeType,
      },
      processOptions: {
        ocrConfig: {
          premiumFeatures: {
            enableMathOcr: true,
            computeStyleInfo: true,
          }
        }
      }
    };
```

And the OCR processor is set to v2.0 in the GCP / terminal for doc ai. Unfortunately, when sending images with clear styles (underlines, bolds, etc) the response object still contains no textStyles information (empty array).

[response object with empty text styles array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVcQF.png)

Did I miss a step somewhere?